# SignalR Persistent connection for android?

Tags: android, signalr, polling, persistent-connection

I successfully implemented Hub connection in signalR but i want to implement persistent connection for my application for continues polling from server. The problem is i didn't find anything about persistent connection in android signalr sdk library nor on net about it. So please if any one have idea about persistent connection implementation please suggest me something,anything.

Thanks in advance!